# AirPrint the UIView Layout using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, airprint

```
import UIKit
extension UIView {
func toImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func sendPrint(sender: AnyObject) {


    let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()


    let printcontroller = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()

    let printinfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)

    printinfo.jobName = "Printing an Image"
    printinfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
    printcontroller.printInfo = printinfo

    //        printcontroller.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()


    printcontroller.showsNumberOfCopies = false


    printcontroller.presentAnimated(true) { (_, isPrinted, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            if isPrinted
            {
                print ("Printed Successfully")
            }   else
            {
                print ("Printing failed")
            }

        }
    }    
}
}
```

I have written this code to AirPrint the `UserInterface` of of my `View`. 
But now code is not working anymore.

---

I am getting runtime error : "attempting to display print options with no printing source (item/items/formatter/renderer) set"

Please help me, I am stuck in this code for the last 3 days.
I just want to generate the image from the `UIView`, which contains 2 or 3 `labels` and an `image`.
[image: My View]

Comment: Try to write "extension UIView" function out side of ViewController class and  check.

Comment: Now... I am getting no error, but code is not working.

Comment: You have to connect printer with device, if not connected.

Comment: I dont think this is the issue.